# Modify Spring boot Embedded Tomcat extract path

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I have realized that when I run spring booth application, embedded tomcat files extracted under `/tmp` file.

Periodic cleanup removes this folder so application gives an error.

Is there any way to modify the path, changing from `/tmp` to `/customfolder.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the property `server.tomcat.basedir`, aren't you?

```
server.tomcat.basedir= # Tomcat base directory. If not specified
                       # a temporary directory will be used.
```

Comment: when I use this propery,  folder is created under what I have given, but it still some tomcat folders are created under tmp like   tomcat-docbase.2399990961165760369.17081

Comment: @AhmetKarakaya, it has not created any files there to me

Comment: as you realise that newly created folder name finisged with "17081" . This is the server port.  Are you establishing a rest service?